# ServerName vs LocalName in ServletRequest

Tags: tomcat, servlets

There are 2 attributes in ServletRequest and would like to understand the difference between the 2.
According to definition in https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html,

```
getServerName(): Returns the host name of the server to which the request was sent.
getLocalName(): Returns the host name of the Internet Protocol (IP) interface on which the request was received.
```

I think both are the hostnames of same entity here.

1. Is it not so?
2. Also what is difference between server and IP interface?

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same:

- `serverName` is the name of the virtual host requested by the HTTP client (cf. [`Host` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host)). This can be overridden by the [`proxyName`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes) value of the connector, the `RemoteIpValve` or the `RewriteValve`,
- `localName` is obtained through a reverse lookup of the local IP (the details depend on the OS).

Basically always use `serverName` to generate URLs.